# How to add dynamic class to multiple dynamic button on click of another button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am developing a nuxt.js web application, I have one static button, and multiple dynamic button, on clicking the static button I want to add class to each dynamic button.

With the code below I am able to add class to the button, but it is only working on first button, on remaining button class are getting added dynamically.

```
<button  @click="scrollToDiv()" class="btn btn-block btn-primary py-2 text-center rounded" style="background: #1f7ae0; border: #1f7ae0;">
```

below is the multiple dynamic button

```
<button id="enroll" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded" style="background: #2685ef;border: 2px solid #2685ef;">Buy Now</button>
<button id="enroll" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded" style="background: #2685ef;border: 2px solid #2685ef;">Buy Now</button>
<button id="enroll" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded" style="background: #2685ef;border: 2px solid #2685ef;">Buy Now</button>
```

Below is the script

```
scrollToDiv() {
    document.getElementById('pricing').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
    })
    var enroll = document.getElementById('enroll')
    enroll.classList.add('glow')
    var scrollTimeout
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout)
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        enroll.classList.remove('glow')
    }, 2000)
}
```

I want to add dynamic CSS to each dynamic button on click of static button

```
.glow {
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(40deg, #2031ffa1, #05ff75cf) !important;
    border-radius: 12px !important;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px #ff922e !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you used nuxt.js, i suppose vue.js solution.

1. append toggle value in data part

```
  data () {
    return {
      ...
      glow: false,
      ...
    }
  }
```

2. Add class binding in each dynamic buttons. `:class="{ glow }"` attributes bind `class name glow` when `glow data` is `true`.

```
<button id="enroll" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded" :class="{glow}" style="background: #2685ef;border: 2px solid #2685ef;">Buy Now</button>
<button id="enroll" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded" :class="{glow}" style="background: #2685ef;border: 2px solid #2685ef;">Buy Now</button>
<button id="enroll" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded" :class="{glow}" style="background: #2685ef;border: 2px solid #2685ef;">Buy Now</button>
```

3. Control just glow data. It affect each button's class name.

```
scrollToDiv() {
  this.glow = true
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.glow = false
  }, 2000)
}
```

4. Set `timeout id` in data (like global variable in component). In your original code, timeout id `scrollTimeout` is local variable in `scrollToDiv`, `clearTimeout` is meaningless. Each execution of scrollToDiv generates new `scrollTimenout` in function scope.

```
  data () {
    return {
      ...
      glow: false,
      timer: null,
      ...
    }
  },
...
  methods: {
    ...
    scrollToDiv() {
      this.glow = true
      clearTimeout(this.timer)
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          this.glow = false
      }, 2000)
    }
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The id of an element is supposed to be unique, so when you use `getElementById` you are only getting the first matching element.
I would try giving the three buttons the same class, and use `getElementsByClassName(className)`, that will return  you an HTMLCollection that will allow you to iterate through the elements. So something like:

```
scrollToDiv() {
  document.getElementById('pricing').scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('example-classname')
  for(let e of elements) e.classList.add('glow')
  var scrollTimeout
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout)
  scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
    for(let e of elements) e.classList.remove('glow')
  }, 2000)
}
```